# How to configure a printer to dump the printout as image or post script file-automatically?

Tags: printing

Today I configure windows printer drivers with FILE:(Print to File) URL.  http://i950.photobucket.com/albums/ad342/jayanmn/image007.png

This way when I goto print files, the application prompts for a filename -- ![alt text][2]

Is it possible configure printer to save files without asking filename?  The FILE: port does not have any configurable values.

![alt text][3]

I am looking this on windows. A Unix/Linux solution should be fine too. ( Note that some other printer ports (PDFCreator) can be configured to save the files without asking user. That is a good workaround)

Comment: I've read this 'question' four times now and I'm still not even close to understanding any of it - can you please rewrite this to be far clearer and give more details.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are using "print to file", rather than a physical printer, and would like to know how to have Windows automatically create a filename instead of prompting for one each time you print. Am I even close to the mark?

Comment: Yes. that is exactly what I am trying. ( I tried to edit the question with images/URL. Not yet got enough credits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- open printer properties
- ports tab
- Add Port...
- Local Port
- C:\TEMP\PrinterFile.prn
- OK, OK

The issue with this approach is that you need to have another process grab C:\TEMP\PrinterFile.prn and process it before another print job comes in and overwrites the file.

Comment: Great help. Thank you!
While this does  not give a control over name for each print, this probably enough for my case. (This is only used for testing. I can control one print at a time)

Thanks